# How can I have 2 leftBarButtonItems in iPhone app, and 1 be the default back button?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I would like 2 leftBarButtonItems, but leave one of the items as the default back button for Navigation Controllers.  I have set up:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:archives, ???, nil];
```

where archives is a UIBarButtonItem I created, but do not know what the default back button is to include in the array.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure you set `leftItemsSupplementBackButton` to YES.

```
self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:archives, nil];
```

Comment: ...but keep in mind that's Available only in iOS 5.0 and later.

Comment: @AnonymousWhite Have you been able to do this with XIB? I am trying the same now with Xcode 5.1.1.